# Independent multi columns for categories highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So basically I have a use case which I couldn't replicate to the existing higcharts example. The scenario is

On X Axis I want to have 5 different categories say `A,B,C,D,E,F`

and now on category `A` I want to have 4 columns with a numerical value (based on Y Axis).

so the way I want to pass data is like

```
data = [
   {
      name:"A",
      data:[
             12, 13, 15, 16   
           ] // They should come as the columns on A and these columns can have different names as well.
   }
]
```

Comment: Not passing the data in that way, no. Not completely clear what you actually want though. Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/eqfuqrLa/

Comment: Or perhaps you are looking for something like the Grouped Categories plugin?  http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories